# Inject to class created via reflection

Tags: spring, reflection, velocity, code-injection

I wanted to use my own implementation of StringResourceRepository from Velocity framework. However I need to use in this implementation injected @Repository. Problem is that Velocity creates my class via reflection, and then uses its method during initialization. Because of that Repository reference is null - nothing is injected. What can I do with this code without modifying Velocity source code?

It seems that one possibility is to implement own StringResourceLoader, but I'm wondering is there any other way to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at @Configurable annotation, this enables spring to inject dependencies into objects that are not directly instantiated by spring. You will need to enable aspectj weaving for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can have Spring do autowiring on an instance you create on your own or one created by a third party library like this:
    WebApplicationContext wac = WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(servletContext);
    wac.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBean(object);

This requires having the ServletContext at hand since there's no global static containing the root WebApplicationContext.

Or if you're setting up velocity in a FactoryBean you can implement WebApplicationContextAware and get the AutowireCapableBeanFactory that way.

Another option is using AspectJ and load time weaving.